# XSLT - How to select the latest formatted date on condition of the attributes of 2 siblings

Tags: date, xslt, max, conditional-statements, siblings

I was provided an xslt file recently to update and I have never used xslt before.  I am trying to select the latest transaction date based on specific attributes of two siblings (ActionType and Status). How would I select a condition based on two siblings and return the date from that section?

I updated my with the provided code, but it's not working:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:for-each select="SupplierConnectInvoice/Invoice | SupplierConnectInvoice/ImageInvoice">
Level1,,<xsl:if test="InvoiceHeader/InvoiceType = 'Original Invoice'">VO</xsl:if><xsl:if test="InvoiceHeader/InvoiceType = 'Credit Invoice'">AD</xsl:if>,<xsl:value-of select="InvoiceHeader/Partner[@PartnerType='Supplier']/Company/CompanyCode" />,<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date(InvoiceHeader/InvoiceDate, 'MM/dd/yyy')" />,<xsl:value-of select="InvoiceHeader/InvoiceNumber" />,

    <xsl:variable name="resubmitted" select="TransactionDateTime[preceding-sibling::ActionType[1]='Submit' and preceding-sibling::Status[1]='Re-Submitted']" as="xs:dateTime*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="submitted" select="TransactionDateTime[preceding-sibling::ActionType[1]='Submit' and preceding-sibling::Status[1]='Submitted']" as="xs:dateTime*"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="count($resubmitted)">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(max($resubmitted),'[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(max($submitted),'[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')"/>             
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

Source Code

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    -<SupplierConnectInvoice xmlns=" " type="A">      
        -<ImageInvoice id="150351390">       
           -<InvoiceHeader>    
                 <InvoiceNumber>494022</InvoiceNumber>        
                 +<Partner PartnerType="Supplier">
                 +<Partner PartnerType="Buyer">
                 <InvoiceDate>2018-12-11</InvoiceDate>
                 <InvoiceType>Original Invoice</InvoiceType>
                 <TransportClass>Supplier_Image_Direct</TransportClass>
                 <Total>1483.78</Total>
                 <SubmittedTotal>1483.78</SubmittedTotal>
                 <TotalLineItems>1</TotalLineItems>
                 <LongDescription>TM General Adv</LongDescription>
                 <CurrencyCode>CAD</CurrencyCode>
                 +<DocumentAction>
                 +<DocumentAction>
                 -<DocumentAction>
                     +<Person Role="DocumentActionPerformer">
                     <ActionType>Forward</ActionType>
                     <Status>Re-Submitted</Status>
                     <TransactionDateTime>2019-05-21T12:54:42</TransactionDateTime> 
               -<DocumentAction>
                     +<Person Role="DocumentActionPerformer">
                     <ActionType>Submit</ActionType>  
                     <Status>Re-Submitted</Status>
                     <LongDescription>please see the amended</LongDescription>
                     <TransactionDateTime>2019-05-21T12:00:42</TransactionDateTime>

               -<DocumentAction>
                     +<Person Role="DocumentActionPerformer">
                     <ActionType>Dispute</ActionType>    
                     <Status>Disputed</Status>
                     <LongDescription>please change</LongDescription>
                     <TransactionDateTime>2019-05-21T08:44:46</TransactionDateTime>

               -<DocumentAction>
                     +<Person Role="DocumentActionPerformer">
                     <ActionType>Submit</ActionType>
                     <Status>Submitted</Status>
                     <LongDescription>Uploaded on 05/17/2019 at 03:53:40 PM MDT</LongDescription>
                     <TransactionDateTime>2019-05-17T15:54:43</TransactionDateTime>
```

Expected results:

If there is ActionType = Submit & Status = Re-Submitted then 05/23/2019 (this would be the latest date of this combination)
If there is no Submit/Re-Submit (in other words ActionType = Submit & Status = Submitted) then 05/17/2019

Actual results is that the latest transaction date is pulled irrespective of the ActionType Status combination when I don't put in the max function.

I error out when the max function on the date

Please and thank you for your help!

Comment: My original post can't seem to save my attempt at this problem but here it is:
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="InvoiceHeader/DocumentAction/Status = 'Re-Submitted'">
<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date(InvoiceHeader/DocumentAction/TransactionDateTime, 'MM/dd/yyy')" />
 </xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date(InvoiceHeader/DocumentAction/TransactionDateTime, 'MM/dd/yyy')" />
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

Comment: I don't follow the logic your describe. Also it's not clear if you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: I'm using xslt 2.0.

Comment: I went and updated my xml source code. Sorry about that! As you can see I have multiple DocumentAction  that occurs throughout my code. i want to loop through to find if there is ActionType = 'Submit' AND Status = 'Re-Submitted'. If there is, return the latest date of the Submit/Resubmitted value combination.  If there is no Submit/Resubmitted value combination, look for ActionType = 'Submit' AND Status = 'Submitted' and retrieve the date that was Submit/Submitted. So in essence, if i ran this to extract details from an xml document, I would expect the retrieval date of 05/24/2019. Make sense?

Comment: That's not XML.

Comment: The source file that I got was a .xml extension and at the beginning of the code before I gave in the snippet starts with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. Are you asking what I tried? I am a bit lost.  Thank you

Comment: What you posted here is not an XML document.

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to understand.

Assuming that your input actually looks something like this:

**XML**

```
<DocumentAction>
       <ActionType>Forward</ActionType>
       <Status>Re-Submitted</Status>
       <TransactionDateTime>2019-05-25T12:00:42</TransactionDateTime>

       <ActionType>Submit</ActionType>
       <Status>Re-Submitted</Status>
       <TransactionDateTime>2019-05-23T12:00:42</TransactionDateTime>

       <ActionType>Submit</ActionType>
       <Status>Re-Submitted</Status>
       <TransactionDateTime>2019-05-21T12:00:42</TransactionDateTime>

       <ActionType>Submit</ActionType>
       <Status>Submitted</Status>
       <TransactionDateTime>2019-05-19T12:00:42</TransactionDateTime>

       <ActionType>Submit</ActionType>
       <Status>Submitted</Status>
       <TransactionDateTime>2019-05-17T12:00:42</TransactionDateTime>
</DocumentAction>
```

you could use the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/DocumentAction">
    <xsl:variable name="resubmitted" select="TransactionDateTime[preceding-sibling::ActionType[1]='Submit' and preceding-sibling::Status[1]='Re-Submitted']" as="xs:dateTime*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="submitted" select="TransactionDateTime[preceding-sibling::ActionType[1]='Submit' and preceding-sibling::Status[1]='Submitted']" as="xs:dateTime*"/>
    <output>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count($resubmitted)">
                <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(max($resubmitted),'[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(max($submitted),'[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')"/>             
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>05/23/2019</output>
```

which is the latest date whose ActionType = 'Submit' AND Status = 'Re-Submitted'.

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38ZJ

---

If you remove these actions, so that the input is:

**XML**

```
<DocumentAction>
       <ActionType>Forward</ActionType>
       <Status>Re-Submitted</Status>
       <TransactionDateTime>2019-05-25T12:00:42</TransactionDateTime>

       <ActionType>Submit</ActionType>
       <Status>Submitted</Status>
       <TransactionDateTime>2019-05-19T12:00:42</TransactionDateTime>

       <ActionType>Submit</ActionType>
       <Status>Submitted</Status>
       <TransactionDateTime>2019-05-17T12:00:42</TransactionDateTime>
</DocumentAction>
```

the result will be:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>05/19/2019</output>
```

which is the latest date whose ActionType = 'Submit' AND Status = 'Submitted'.

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ38ZJ/1

---

### Added:

A more elegant version of the same idea:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/DocumentAction">
    <xsl:variable name="resubmitted" select="TransactionDateTime[preceding-sibling::ActionType[1]='Submit' and preceding-sibling::Status[1]='Re-Submitted']" as="xs:dateTime*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="submitted" select="TransactionDateTime[preceding-sibling::ActionType[1]='Submit' and preceding-sibling::Status[1]='Submitted']" as="xs:dateTime*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="latest-dateTime" select="if (count($resubmitted)) then max($resubmitted) else max($submitted)"/>
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($latest-dateTime,'[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]')"/>                
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried using your solution and it's failing. One of the items that I did not use is <xsl:template match="/DocumentAction">. I am using <xsl:template match="/"> instead since I have other elements that i need to pull. Would this be why this is failing? If so, what do I need to do to get it running?

Comment: I don't know. I can only answer on the basis of what I can see. Even the above is based largely on a guess of what your XML looks like. In any case, there can be only one root element, so having `<xsl:template match="/DocumentAction">` should not prevent you from processing "other elements that need to pull" )(whatever that means).